# sql converting date to show

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the total `sum` from a the table from the `previous` day. I get an error

My code:

```
select 
    date_paid, sum(paid_amount) as amount 
from 
    till1 
where
    date_paid = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) 
group by 
    date_paid
```

I want to get a result something like this:

[image]

I get the following error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Comment: Apparently, `date_paid` is being stored as a string.  That is a bad way to store dates (as you can see because this query fails).  Fix your data.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this is SQL Server.  You can fix the syntax error by using `try_convert()`:

```
select date_paid, sum(paid_amount) as amount
from till1 
where try_convert(date, date_paid) = cast(getdate() as date)
group by date_paid;
```

However, the real solution is to fix the data.  Dates should not be stored as strings.

Comment: the field that has "date_paid" contains NULL values, but if i use a field that doesn't have NULL values, it gives me the right results,, how do i make it ignore NULL fields and make give me the results?

Comment: @fhulufhelohanyahanya . . . `NULL` values would fail the comparison, but not cause a query error.  The issue is that the column is a string and not a date/time.

Comment: thank you, its working, but my  date_paid data format has changed from "2017/410/13" to "2017-10-13 00:00:00.000"